# Iterate through a string and append static values to a list for every occurrence of substring (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I'm currently stuck on some basic Python. I currently have a very long html string that looks something like this:

`<relative-time class="no-wrap" datetime="2023-03-07T02:38:29Z" title="Mar 6, 2023, 7:38 PM MST">Mar 6, 2023</relative-time>, <relative-time data-view-component="true" datetime="2023-03-06T10:25:38-07:00`

I want to iterate through and, at every substring = "datetime", store the date that follows.

My current implementation is that I have two lists.  One list stores the index of the .find() method for datetimes so:

```
datetime_indexes = list(get_all_updates(string, "datetime"))
print(datetime_indexes)
#output 36, 168 etc
```

Next, I have a loop to go through the string and, if the index that I'm currently on in that string matches a value stored in my index list, append the datetime value to a new list.

```
count = 0
all_datetimes = []
for i in string:
    if string.index(i) is datetime_indexes[count]:
        all_datetimes.append(string[string.index(i) + 10:(string.index(i) + 10 + 21)])
        count = count + 1
```

Currently, it outputs the first "datetime" value that I'm looking for:

```
#output
#2023-03-07T02:38:29Z
```

The desired result here would be to show all datetime values, so:

```
#desired output
2023-03-07T02:38:29
2023-03-06T10:25:38
```

Comment: Have you checked out `Beautiful Soup`?  It may be a huge help here.

Comment: Wouldn't a regex suffice? Something like `re.findall(r'datetime="([^"]+)"')`?

Comment: Currently using it, actually.  That string is returned from a soup object i.e. `new_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')` and then I did something like `new_soup.find_all("relative-time")` and then converted that to a string which is what you see in the post

Comment: What is the logic behind the first date including something after the seconds but the other not?

Comment: @ScottHunter, that is actually omitted in the updated code-- just used one less value for the retrieval. Just a mistake when typing the code out here. Edit: I copy pasted the output and just accidentally added that character, fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Beautiful Soup was made to do:

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then you can do:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """
<relative-time class="no-wrap" datetime="2023-03-07T02:38:29Z" title="Mar 6, 2023, 7:38 PM MST">Mar 6, 2023</relative-time>,
<relative-time data-view-component="true" datetime="2023-03-06T10:25:38-07:00">asdf</relative-time>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
date_list = [tag["datetime"] for tag in soup.findAll(attrs={"datetime" : True})]
print(date_list)
```

That will give you:

```
['2023-03-07T02:38:29Z', '2023-03-06T10:25:38-07:00']
```

Since you were already using BeautifulSoup, I think the key part here is `find_all("relative-time")` being replaced with `findAll(attrs={"datetime" : True})` to get all tags with an attribute `datetime`

Comment: Well, that is perfect.  Thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for-- I have been converting soups to string and trying to move through those without actually using the attributes. Thank you!

Comment: New question:  Out of curiosity, if there was a tag above all of these tags i.e. an href link (but in its own tag), is there a way to associate them with each other? These exist in the soup object. 
`<a class="Link--secondary ml-2" data-pjax="#repo-content-pjax-container" data-turbo-frame="repo-content-turbo-frame" href="link_here">
<relative-time class="no-wrap" datetime="2023-03-07T02:38:29Z" title="Mar 6, 2023, 7:38 PM MST">Mar 6, 2023</relative-time>`